# Ubuntu smart phones

Tags: phone

Is it possible to install Ubuntu programs like different desktops environments on Ubuntu Touch compatible phones?

I would like to install an Integrated Development Environment with a GNU compiler on them.

*Is this possible?*

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [Ubuntu Touch SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/) can only be installed on full-fledged PCs, so **no, there are currently no IDEs that run on the actual phone hardware.**

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**